Applying the linearity property of determinants to find the determinant of a matrix
Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \text{row 1} \\ \text{row 2} \\ \text{row 3}\end{bmatrix} B = \begin{bmatrix} \text{row 1 + row 2 + row 3} \\ \text{row 1 + row 2} \\ \text{row 1} \end{bmatrix}
$$
If det(A) = 6, find the determinant of B
Here's my attempt:
Using the linearity property of determinants,
$$
\begin{align}
det(B) &= det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r1 +r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r2 \\ r1 +r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r3 \\ r1 +r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r1 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r2 \\ r1 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r2 \\ r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r3 \\ r1 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r3 \\ r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r3 \\ r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r3 \\ r2 \\ r1\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= det\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r2 \\ r3\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= det\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\right) det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r2 \\ r3\end {bmatrix}\right) \\
det(B) &= (-1) det\left(\begin{bmatrix} r1 \\ r2 \\ r3\end {bmatrix}\right) = -6
\end{align}
$$
did I do it correctly?

It seems true. But it can be calculated simply by row transformation. The $2$nd row is added to $1$st row.

@fusheng how would i do that? I don't understand what you mean

Since $B = \begin{bmatrix} \text{row 1 + row 2 + row 3} \ \text{row 1 + row 2} \ \text{row 1} \end{bmatrix}$, you can add the second row of $B$, multiplied by $-1$, to the first row of $B$. Then you add the third row of $B$, multiplied by $-1$, to the second row of $B$.     Finally,  you will get $|B| =\begin{bmatrix} \text{ row 3} \ \text{ row 2} \ \text{row 1} \end{bmatrix}$.  Since $|A|=6$, then $|B|=-6$. It is properties of determinants,

What is the linearity property of determinants?  It’s not true in general that $\det(A+B)=\det(A)+\det(B)$; consider $A=I$ and $B=2I$

@J.W.Tanner Maybe i should've been more specific. Gilbert Strang's textbook calls it "the determinant is a linear function of each row separately". I don't really like the way he calls it, so I came up with an easier term to understand: linearity property of determinants. Maybe I should've changed it to linearity property for separate rows of a matrix's determinant

Oh, perhaps you mean multilinearity

Yes, correct. @J.W.Tanner
